# Eigen::Quaternionf, how can I access the values?

Tags: c++, eigen, quaternions

I am trying to use Eigen in an existing project, and am stuck.

I am creating a `quaternionf` from a matrix, like so:

`Eigen::Quaternionf quats(path.block(0, 0, 3, 3));`

The matrix is valid, and this construction should work.

When i try to call the x,y,z,w values though, like this:

`float test = quats.x();`

It will not compile, giving me:

`use of undefined type 'Eigen::internal::quaternionbase_assign_impl<MatrixDerived,-1,-1>'`

in:

`\eigen\src\Geometry\Quaternion.h`

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not is `quats.x()` but in the initialization:

```
Eigen::Quaternionf quats(path.block(0, 0, 3, 3));
```

You must tell Eigen that your are passing a 3x3 matrix at compile time:

```
Eigen::Quaternionf quats(path.block<3,3>(0, 0));
```

or even:

```
Eigen::Quaternionf quats(path.topLeftCorner<3,3>());
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thank you!